# How to draw user input into a texture in Unreal

Tags: unreal-engine4

On mobile platforms, users can draw things directly on the screen.
I know how to do this,we can use drawline.
But how can i draw userinput into a texture for processing or save it?
The screenshot is not good enough,i only want the part drawn by the user.
give me some ideas
please

Comment: You could record the information used to draw each line. If you need that on a texture, then just redraw it and render it to a texture in an empty scene.

Comment: thanks! but i did it in another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use renderTexture2D,and draw Material on it